# How can I perform validation on a secure password. Regular expressions on a char[]?

Tags: java, regex, validation, passwords, arrays

This question is a follow up on the question here:

[Why is char[] preferred over String for passwords?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8881291/975724)

That question is great for understanding why it is good to use a char[] instead of a String; however, it doesn't explain how to perform password validation on a char[] in a secure manner.  That is what I would like to know about here.

Put simply, I need to check to see if a password meets the following requirements:

- Contains at least one uppercase letter
- Contains at least one lowercase letter
- Contains at least one digit
- Contains at least one symbol
- Is at least *n* characters, but no more than *m*

Now I understand how I can use regular expressions to perform the validation... these answers show how to do that:

- [Regexp Java for password validation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3802238/975724)
- [Password must be 8 characters including 1 uppercase letter, 1 special character, alphanumeric characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9478035/975724)

As far as I know, regular expression checks involve working with strings.  It doesn't seem secure to use them because strings are immutable, and thus they cannot be cleared immediately after using them.  A char[], on the other hand, can be cleared.

### So, how can I perform validation on a password which is stored in a char[], and not a string?

I could iterate through each character, but then I would have to create each set that I want to test.  Ideally, it would be useful to be able to take advantage of regular expressions.

In Java, I can do regular expressions check via the following methods.

```
String.matches(String regex)
```

Or

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(String regex);
pattern.matcher(CharSequence testString).matches();
```

As you can see, both methods do not support working directly with a char[].

Comment: No experience with doing so, so I don't know the security ramifications, but, you could compile your own `Pattern` and use `matcher(CharSequence)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would try to avoid a complicated regex, I would suggest something like -

```
boolean validatePassword(char[] password, int n, int m) {
  if (password == null || password.length < n || password.length > m) {
    return false;
  }
  boolean upper = false;
  boolean lower = false;
  boolean digit = false;
  boolean symbol = false;
  for (char ch : password) {
    if (Character.isUpperCase(ch)) {
      upper = true;
    } else if (Character.isLowerCase(ch)) {
      lower = true;
    } else if (Character.isDigit(ch)) {
      digit = true;
    } else { // or some symbol test.
      symbol = true;
    }
    // This short-circuits the rest of the loop when all criteria are true.
    if (upper && lower && digit && symbol) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return upper && lower && digit && symbol;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Although this doesn't use regex, it still does the validation.  I was unaware of `Character.isLower/Upper/Digit()` fucntions.  If the goal is to erase the password, shouldn't the local char[] be zeroed-out?

Comment: @NickMiller Generally, I'd prefer to let the caller dispose of it. Once this method completes you know the password is valid only as a password (not a correct password per se), you haven't actually done anything with it yet (as far as this method knows anyway).

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong, but isn't the char[] inside the method a copy?  And if it is a copy, it should be cleared out because we do not want to wait until the GC activates.

Comment: @NickMiller *Good news*! You're incorrect. It is not a copy. Java is pass by value, but the value of Object(s), **including** Array(s), is the reference.

Comment: Ah! I get it, the reference is copied, but both references point to the same memory! :)

Answer (score 4):

Just iterate through `char[]` to do basic password acceptance validation

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`CharBuffer.wrap(char[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/CharBuffer.html#wrap-char:A-) to access the char array as a `CharSequence`.

```java
Pattern.matches(regex, CharBuffer.wrap(myCharArray))
```

Answer (score 2):

Java's regex implementation does not require `String` objects - you are expected to pass a [`CharSequence`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html). If you would rather not create a `String` from a `char[]` array, you could wrap an array in your own implementation of the `CharSequence` interface.

Comment: I like this since `CharSequence` can contain a mutable `char[]` in the background.  I could just restrict access and provide a function to clear the array when I'm finished.  My only concern is whether or not the the regex functions store the character data.