# Regex for 1 uppercase 1 special character and 1 lowercase

Tags: regex

I need a regex for 1 uppercase 1 special character and 1 lowercase 
Note need to allow all special character and it should be above 8 character in length.

I have tried   `/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{8,}$/` this but this is restricting some special character.

Comment: Is this for password checking? - which language?

Comment: How about this http://stackoverflow.com/a/32761797/179669

Comment: yes password checking javascript

Comment: @Bakudan I prefer http://stackoverflow.com/a/9478691/1804181

Answer (score 9):

Try to use this regex:

```
^(?=.{8,})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+*!=]).*$
```

**[REGEX DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/pA2nM7/2)**

**Explanation:**

```
(/^
(?=.{8,})                //should be 8 characters or more
(?=.*[a-z])             //should contain at least one lower case
(?=.*[A-Z])             //should contain at least one upper case
(?=.*[@#$%^&+*!=])      //should contain at least 1 special characters
.*$/)
```

Comment: great explanation and use of the regex demo! +1 thanks! a new site in my repertoire of useful utilities

Comment: @Madivad:- You are welcome!

Answer (score 3):

I would use:

```
^(?=.{8,})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^\w\d]).*$
```

Note that `[^\w\d]` allow *any* special char.

Comment: This would *require* any special character. Thanks!