# I need to write a read string method for a console application that has a few policies

Tags: c#, string, methods, passwords, visual-studio-2015

The policies im trying to apply are that it has to be 3 characters long, that it must include a lower case letter, an upper case letter and a number in any order. Im trying to use it as a method to read in a password set by the user for an assignment.I have written as much as i can to emiminate errors but i cant figure out a way to apply said policies. this is what i have so far... Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
    private static string readPass() { //readpass method to read in password of 1 lower case, 1 upper case & 1 number


        bool validInput = true;
        char letterUserInput;                                           //letter from string
        int asciiCodeLetter;                                            //number code for letter
        string userInput;

        do {
            validInput = true;
            userInput = Console.ReadLine();
        try {

                if (userInput.Length < 1) {
                    validInput = false;
                    Console.WriteLine("You have just pressed Enter Please Enter a valid Password");
                }                      //if check length

                else if (userInput.Length > 1 && userInput.Length < 3) {
                    validInput = false;
                    Console.WriteLine("Password Is Too Short. Please Enter Valid Password");
                }                                                       //if check length too short

                else if (userInput.Length > 3)
                {
                    validInput = false;
                    Console.WriteLine("Password Is Too Long. Please Enter A Valid Password");
                }                                                       //if check length too short

                for (int i = 0; i < userInput.Length; i++)              //take each letter in turn from string
                {
                    letterUserInput = userInput[i];
                    asciiCodeLetter = Convert.ToInt16(letterUserInput);
                    if (asciiCodeLetter < 48 || asciiCodeLetter > 57)
                    {
                        validInput = false;
                        Console.WriteLine("You have used an invalid character.\n Password Must Contain 1 Upper Case, 1 Lower Case letter and 1 Number)");
                    }                                                    //character check with ASCII
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                validInput = false;
                Console.WriteLine("An unspecified error has occured");
            }                                                           //catch

            if (validInput == false) Console.Write("Invalid Password. Please Enter Again = ");

        } while (validInput == false);                                  // do. repeat entry if invalid

        return userInput;
    }
```

Comment: You could eliminate the `userInput.Length > 1 && ` in the second else if. Because that block will only be executed if first `if` is not satisfied.

Comment: why don't you try this link.. there is a c# example as well as a 1 liner example using `Regex` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477906/password-must-be-8-characters-including-1-uppercase-letter-1-special-character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expressions for this:

```
var input = Console.ReadLine();
var regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("^([0-9][a-z][A-Z]|[0-9][A-Z][a-z]|[a-z][0-9][A-Z]|[a-z][A-Z][0-9]|[A-Z][a-z][0-9]|[A-Z][0-9][a-z])$");
validInput = input != null && regex.IsMatch(input);
```

I'm sure there are more fancy Regex for this. But this is simply enough to understand it if you are not familiar with Regex expressions.

### Edit

You can use the following Regex if you want something more fancy:

```
 var input = Console.ReadLine();
 var regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{3}$");
 validInput = input != null && regex.IsMatch(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

Some pseudocode for this might be:

```
String candidatePwd = textboxPwd.Text.Trim();
Boolean validPwd = IsValidPassword(candidatePwd);

private bool IsValidPassword(String candidate)
{
    return ((candidate.Length == 3) &&
            (ContainsOneUppercaseLetter(candidate)) &&
            (ContainsOneLowerCaseLetter(candidate)) &&
            (ContainsOneNumber(candidate)));
}

private bool ContainsOneUppercaseLetter(String candidate)
{
   // search for an uppercase letter; if one found, return true
}

private bool ContainsOneLowercaseLetter(String candidate)
{
   // search for a lowercase letter; if one found, return true
}

private bool ContainsOneUppercaseLetter(String candidate)
{
   // search for a number; if one found, return true
}
```

The actual implementation is left to you.

Answer (score 0):

For 3 chars - simply save the password written by user as a string, then check it length. If it comes to upper case, I would convert every char on ASCII code, then check if any code is equal to the code of all upper case letters. For checking if there is a number, check every char of your password using something like this

> int n; bool isNumeric = int.TryParse("123", out n);

Hope that will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regular expression:

> ^.*(?=.{3,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*$

and simplify your code:

```
if(!Regex.IsMatch(userInput, "^.*(?=.{7,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*$")
  Console.WriteLine("The password has to be 3 characters long, and must include a lower case letter, an upper case letter, and a number");
```