# Negating a regex for use MVC validation attributes

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, validation, c#-4.0, regex-negation

Can we negate this expression, if no match found to return true for use in regex attributes (MVC dataannotations)?

Pattern should match:

1. anything with less than 8 characters OR
2. anything with no numbers OR
3. anything with no uppercase OR
4. anything with no special characters

**I want to negate** this expression/pattern

```
[RegularExpression(@"^(.{0,7}|[^0-9]*|[^A-Z]*|[a-zA-Z0-9]*)$")]
```

I tried `?!` with no success:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^(?!.{0,7}|[^0-9]*|[^A-Z]*|[a-zA-Z0-9]*)$")]
```

Refering to this answer: [Regex password validation, reverse logic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33589835/2581562)

Comment: You can try `"^(?!(?:.{0,7}|[^0-9]*|[^A-Z]*|[a-zA-Z0-9]*)$).*$"`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, passive non capturing group was the missing part.
Thank you it works! You can post it as an answer and i will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To negate an expression containing several anchored alternatives, you need to group them inside an anchored negative lookahead.

Thus, just add a group (either capturing or non-capturing):

```
"^(?!(?:.{0,7}|[^0-9]*|[^A-Z]*|[a-zA-Z0-9]*)$).*$"
```

Since a `RegularExpressionAttribute` needs a full string match, I added `.*$`.