# Strong password checker

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating a simple code to check if a password is secure. To be secure a password be at least 8 characters and have one special character. My code does not work properly when 8 characters are entered without a special character. How can I fix it?

```
#get password
password_in = input("Enter a secure password: ")

#check password is secure
special_ch = ['!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*']

check = any(item in special_ch for item in password_in)

while len(password_in) <8 and check == False: 
    print("Password is not secure") 
    password_in = input("Please enter a secure password: ")
```

Comment: "My code doesn't work properly" What is the error?

Comment: `and` should be `or`.

Comment: check is not a very good variable name. you should better use something like special_char_used

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression to check if password is "8 characters including 1 uppercase letter, 1 special character, alphanumeric characters"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477906/regular-expression-to-check-if-password-is-8-characters-including-1-uppercase-l)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `and` to `or`:

```
while len(password_in) <8 or check is False: 
    ...
```

Alternatively, to achieve the same result, put in the exact conditions you're looking for and negate all of it:

```
while not(len(password_in) >= 8 and check is True):
    ...
```

The fact that these two are logically equivalent is an example of [DeMorgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).