# A regular expression to match a string with alphabets AND numbers with length greater than n?

Tags: java, regex

I wish to write a regex that will match strings with numbers.

I have the following regular expression which kind of works:

```
[a-z0-9]*([a-z]+[0-9]+)+[a-z0-9]*
```

results:

```
abc1234aa121aaa //Matches
abc123  //Matches
12abc123sd12 //Matches
abcaaaaaa //Does not match
ab12b12b12b2321b3  //Matches
ab12b12b12b2321b //Matches
1abc1234aa121aaa //Matches
v2  //Matches
```

but it doesn't work if I wanted to match strings with length 5 or greater

```
([a-z0-9]*([a-z]+[0-9]+)+[a-z0-9]*){5,}
```

Comment: Edited the question with my attempt.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression to check if password is "8 characters including 1 uppercase letter, 1 special character, alphanumeric characters"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477906/regular-expression-to-check-if-password-is-8-characters-including-1-uppercase-l)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?=\w{5,})\w*[0-9]+\w*
```

This should help you. This regex matches any string of word characters (That's the \w*[0-9]+\w*, where \w is shorthand for [a-zA-Z0-9_])

At the beginning, there is a positive lookahead which asserts that there are at least 5 word characters in a row in the match. This way, any less than 5 characters in the word will fail the lookahead.

Comment: @Siddharth: Be aware this is matching strings without letters like: `123456789` or `__123__`

Answer (score 0):

In the first pattern `v2` matches but as you have a fixed order `[a-z]+[0-9]+` then `2v` would for example not match.

As you use a quantifier `{5,}` in the second pattern and use `[a-z]+[0-9]+` the minimum length would be at least 10.

If you want to `match a string with alphabets AND numbers with length greater than n` so only digits should not match, you could use:

```
\b(?=[a-z0-9]{5,})(?=[a-z0-9]*[a-z])[a-z0-9]*[0-9][a-z0-9]*\b
```

- `\b` Word boundary
- `(?=[a-z0-9]{5,})` Assert 5 or more times a char a-z or a digit 0-9
- `(?=[a-z0-9]*[a-z])` Assert at least 1 char a-z
- `[a-z0-9]*` Match 0+ times a-z or 0-9
- `[0-9]` Match a digit 0-9
- `[a-z0-9]*` Match 0+ times a-z or 0-9
- `\b` Word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/s5HDjc/1)

In Java

```
String regex = "\\b(?=[a-z0-9]{5,})(?=[a-z0-9]*[a-z])[a-z0-9]*[0-9][a-z0-9]*\\b";
```